# Problem with Auth.js file for a login with SQL Server and Hapi.Dev

Tags: node.js, sql-server, hapi.js

I'm coding for first time with Hapi and my database is in SQL Server, I have a table of "users" in it, but when I submit the credentials for login in my `auth.js` file there is a function "find" is not working.

```
server.auth.strategy( "session", "cookie", {
        cookie: {
            name: "amst-auth",
            path: "/",
            password: config.cookiePwd,
            isSecure: false
        },
        redirectTo: "/login",
        validateFunc: async( request, session ) => {
            try{
                const db = request.server.plugins.sql.client;
                const res = await db.usuario.allUsers(  );
                //console.log( res.recordset );
                const account = await res.recorset.find(
                    ( res ) => ( res.NOM_USUARIO === session.NOM_USUARIO )
                );

                if( !account ){
                    return { valid: false };
                }

                return { valid: true, credentials: account };
            }catch( err ) {
                //console.log( session.NOM_USUARIO );
                console.log( err );
            }
        }
    } );
```

[image: Here is the error, the function find works before in my code an exactly with the same sintaxis]

Here is the error, the function find works before in my code an exactly with the same sintaxis

[image: Commented console.log(res.recordset) result]

Commented console.log(res.recordset) result

[image: Commented console.log(session.NOM_USUARIO) result]

Commented console.log(session.NOM_USUARIO) result

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined.` So, should `res.recorset.find` instead be `res.recordset.find`?

Comment: Thank you man, I haven't seen that... Sometimes 4 eyes is better than 2